# PHP fwrite can not write to a txt file

Tags: php, centos, centos7, fwrite

I'm using CentOS7. My index.html, action.php and file.txt are all in the same folder. I have already set `chown apache:apache` to the entire /var/www/html tree. The file does get open but I am not able to write anything to it. It's my first ever PHP code, so please let me know if I'm being stupid or something. The var_dump($_POST); works fine as well.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['fname'];
$fp = fopen("file.txt","w") or die("Can not open file");
fwrite("file.txt",$name) or die ("can not write to file");
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the file handle resource in this case `$fp`, and not the name.

So this:

```
$name = $_POST['fname'];
$fp = fopen("file.txt","w") or die("Can not open file");
fwrite("file.txt",$name) or die ("can not write to file");
```

Should be:

```
//if(!empty($_POST['fname'])){ ..you should really check this
$name = $_POST['fname'];
$fp = fopen("file.txt","w") or die("Can not open file");
fwrite($fp,$name) or die ("can not write to file");
```

For reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

> int **fwrite**( resource **$handle**, string **$string** [, int **$length** ] )

That said in a case like this, writing a single line.

```
if(!file_put_contents("file.txt", $name)) die ("can not write to file");
```

Is a bit easier to use.  But in any case these 2 things you don't need to do:

```
fclose($fp);
?>
```

The file is closed when PHP is done, and the ending tag can actually cause more issues then it's worth.  The only time I use `fclose` is if I open a file and read from it and then delete it with `unlink` you can't `unlink` it if its open, otherwise I just let PHP close it.  The ending tag is only needed if you plan to follow the PHP code with something like HTML.  Having space (for example) after an ending tag can corrupt file downloads because any content that is output will be included in a download. What's worse is if you included a file that has the space (or other stuff) it can be really hard to find out why you can't open a zip file you sent as a download (for example).

Cheers, and good luck.

Comment: Thanks a ton. That solved the problem. I knew I was doing something stupid.

Comment: It's ok, happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the file object to the function

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['fname'];
$fp = fopen("file.txt","w") or die("Can not open file");
fwrite($fp,$name) or die ("can not write to file");
fclose($fp);
?>
```